# ICU Static linking on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode, linker, icu

Alright, so I want to link ICU into my project. Here's what I did:
I went to ICU's github, and downloaded the master repo.

I extracted it, and opened it up.

I then opened All In One and then set all the projects to build a static-lib, and also set
`U_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION`.

I then rebuilt all. 4 projects, the makedata projects, and uwp projects, failed. But everything else was OK.

Then, I created a new test project.

I then added the built .libs from the common, stubdata, i18n directories. (lib64 was empty because I set build config to static-lib)

And it seemed to work, and link in.

However, the issue is that while UTF-8 works, things like Big-5 and basically every other encoding didn't work.

So I tried downloading the latest-release binaries. And those worked perfectly!!! The only issue was that the required the .dll files or it would pop up a runtime error. I'm desperate at this point.

Comment: Why did you tag [tag:linker], while you're saying this doesn't seem to be a linking problem, and the code is running?Note that we have an [tag:icu] tag alternatively, it's probably more appropriate to address a specifically expertised audience. Though I bielieve all of this told in prose, should come along with a [mcve] to help diagnosing the problem.

Comment: what happens when you try to use other encodings? Is there an error? etc.

Comment: @jwezorek No. What happens is the functions just return null.